# "There is already an object named '' in the database" When table should be created only if it does not exist

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to create the new table only if it does not already exist in the database. So I use the following:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'FactSend'))
BEGIN
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

    CREATE TABLE [MyDB].[dbo].[FactSend](
        [Id] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [FlowId] [int] NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](550) NULL,
        [Channel] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [Date] [datetime] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_FactSend] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    ALTER TABLE [MyDB].[dbo].[FactSend]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactSend_DimFlow] FOREIGN KEY([FlowId])
    REFERENCES [MyDB].[dbo].[DimFlow] ([Id])

    ALTER TABLE [MyDB].[dbo].[FactSend] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactSend_DimFlow]
END
```

But I get the following error:

> There is already an object named 'FactSend' in the database.

I know there is, that is why I put that in an IF so that the `CREATE` is skipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too long for a comment but a wild guess. The database you're connected to isn't `MyDB` and so you're checking in a different database for the existence of `FactSend`; and then trying to create it in `MyDB`. Does the following work?

```
USE MyDB;
GO

IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
               WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
               AND TABLE_NAME = 'FactSend'))
BEGIN
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FactSend](
        [Id] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [FlowId] [int] NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](550) NULL,
        [Channel] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [Date] [datetime] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_FactSend] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactSend]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_FactSend_DimFlow] FOREIGN KEY([FlowId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[DimFlow] ([Id])

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FactSend] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FactSend_DimFlow]
END
```

When referencing an object with 2 part naming (i.e. `dbo.MyTable`, `sys.columns`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`), the database you are currently connected to will be used. Writing a query/statement with a 3 part naming convention does not change the context of the database you are using (just like using 4 part naming convention doesn't change the server you are connected to).

I suspect that you were connected to the default database; probably `master`. As a result your `EXISTS` checked in the database `master` for the table `dbo.FactSend`.

In effect, your query was more like the below:

```
USE master;

IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM master.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES --technically master isn't needed here, it's just to show the point
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'FactSend'))
BEGIN
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

    CREATE TABLE [MyDB].[dbo].[FactSend](
        [Id] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [FlowId] [int] NULL,
    ...
```

So, to confirm, you were checking to the existence of the object `master.dbo.FactSend` and then, if that didn't exist, creating the object `MyDB.dbo.FactSend`. Of course, that means that no matter how many times you do(try to) create the `MyDB.dbo.FactSend`, it'll never mean the object `master.dbo.FactSend` exists; so the `NOT EXISTS` will always evaluate to true.

Making sure you are connected to the right database is really important. Personally, when using scripts to create objects I recommend against using 3 part naming. Instead declare your database prior (using `USE`), and then create your objects using 2 part naming. That way you always know the context of the database the objects are being created in, can't "accidental" create them in the wrong one, and if you need to change the database (maybe you're scripting them to a different database) you only need to change the `USE` statement and not *every* reference. *Of course, if you are referring to objects in other databases then you'd have to use 3 part naming, but I'm specifically talking about when everything in tidily in one DB.*

Comment: Yes this solved the issue. This has happened before. Why, even though specifically mention the database name when I name the tables? it is still unable to understand what i mean? If you add the explanation I will gladly accept this as answer.

Comment: The problem was that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` didn't mention the database, @Disasterkid. I go into more detail in the answer for you now.

Comment: @tezzo that wouldn't work. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` only returns details for a single database (in this case the one you are connected to). You would need to use `MyDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to get the details from a different database.